# What is actual role of combiner in java parallelStream reduce

Tags: java, mapreduce, java-stream, reduce

I have basic understanding of `reduce` method in java stream. However, the role of combiner in `parallelStream` is not clear to me. In the code snippet below, in the first block I have used a combiner and it is not there in the second block. However the result is same in both cases.

```
List<Integer> intarr = Arrays.asList(10,20,30);
        Integer totsum = intarr.stream().reduce(20, (a,b) -> a+b, (a,b) -> a+b);
        System.out.println("total sum: "+totsum);

List<Integer> intarr = Arrays.asList(10,20,30);
        Integer totsum = intarr.stream().reduce(20, (a,b) -> a+b);
        System.out.println("total sum: "+totsum);
```

It is understood that in case of 2 param [`reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce(T,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)) method the accumulator is a `BinaryOperator` and is `BiFunction` in case of 3 param [`reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce(U,java.util.function.BiFunction,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)) method. And it is also known that this will help in type conversion. For an example if I need to convert int to double, I can specify my identity as 20.0 and combiner will output it in the type of double.

But what advantage are we actually getting by using a combiner apart from type conversion?

Answer (score 1):

The point of the combiner is to handle when the result and the inputs are of *different types*, which isn't the case here.  For example, if you wanted a String concatenation, you could do it with `reduce` by writing

```
stream.reduce("", (String str, int i) -> str + i, (String a, String b) -> a + b)
```

...in which case, when the stream was reduced in *parallel*, different chunks would be accumulated separately and then combined with the combiner.

Answer (score 1):

The signature of the [3-arg version](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) is:

```java
<U> U reduce(U identity,
             BiFunction<U,? super T,U> accumulator,
             BinaryOperator<U> combiner)
```

It intended for use when one (or both) of the following is true:

- The result type (`U`) is different from the stream element type (`T`).
- The `combiner` is different from the `accumulator`.

If none of those are true, then the [2-arg version](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-T-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) is better (simpler, easier):

```java
T reduce(T identity,
         BinaryOperator<T> accumulator)
```

For the example shown in the question, there is no advantage to using the 3-arg version.

---

Examples for having different types are plenty, e.g. see the other answers.

An example where the types are the same, but the `combiner` is `accumulator`, would be for the `-` minus operator:

```
List<Integer> intarr = Arrays.asList(10,20,30);

// Sequential processing doesn't use combiner: totsum = -60
Integer totsum = intarr.stream().reduce(0, (a,b) -> a - b, (a,b) -> a - b);

// Parallel processing with same combiner does work: totsum = -20
Integer totsum = intarr.parallelStream().reduce(0, (a,b) -> a - b);

Integer totsum = intarr.parallelStream().reduce(0, (a,b) -> a - b, (a,b) -> a - b);

// Parallel processing requires a different combiner: totsum = -60
Integer totsum = intarr.parallelStream().reduce(0, (a,b) -> a - b, (a,b) -> a + b);
```

That is because with parallel processing, we get 3 threads for that input stream, so the code becomes:

```java
thread1Result = accumulator.apply(0/*identity*/, 10);  // = 0 - 10 = -10

thread2Result = accumulator.apply(0/*identity*/, 20);  // = 0 - 20 = -20

thread3Result = accumulator.apply(0/*identity*/, 30);  // = 0 - 30 = -30

// Bad combiner: (a,b) -> a - b
result = combiner.apply(thread1Result, thread2Result); // = -10 - -20 = +10
result = combiner.apply(result, thread3Result);        // = +10 - -30 = -20

// Good combiner: (a,b) -> a + b
result = combiner.apply(thread1Result, thread2Result); // = -10 + -20 = -30
result = combiner.apply(result, thread3Result);        // = -30 + -30 = -60
```

Comment: "// Parallel processing requires a different combiner: totsum = -20" should be -60?

Comment: @samabcde Dang all copy/paste errors to hell. Thanks!!

Comment: // = +10 - -30 = -20
how can it be possible? It should be 40, but the output is really -20. How?

Answer (score 1):

It is not that using a combiner is more "advantageous" over not using a combiner. The two overloads of `reduce` are made for different purposes. It is as you have identified, type conversion.

`reduce(T, BinaryOperator<T>)`, without the combiner, returns a `T` - the same type of thing that is in the stream pipeline. On the other hand, `reduce(U, BiFunction<U, ? super T, U>, BinaryOperator<U>)`, with the combiner, returns a `U` - a different type than what is in the stream.

```
BigInteger sum = bigIntegerStream.reduce(BigInteger.ZERO, BigInteger::add);
```

I could use the combiner-less version to, say, add up a stream of `BigInteger`s. The stream would be a `Stream<BigInteger>`, and the result I want is of type `BigInteger` too. And I could use the combiner version to sum a `Stream<Long>` to a `BigInteger`. Notice how the type of the stream is different from the result type I want.

```
BigInteger sum = longStream.reduce(BigInteger.ZERO, (bi, l) -> bi.add(BigInteger.valueOf(l)), BigInteger::add);
```

Arguably, you could have also done a `map` before a using the combiner-less `reduce`.

The reason why a combiner is needed when the result type is different from the type of the stream is because a `reduce` operation can be run in parallel. For example, the whole stream could be split into several sections, and each section reduced in parallel.

If the result type is the same as the stream type `T`, then each section would be reduced to a `T` using the binary operator provided, and we are left with a bunch of `T`s. We can further reduce this bunch of `T`s to a single `T` using that same binary operator.

If the result type `U` is different from the stream type `U`, then the `BiFucntion` will reduce each section to a `U`, and we are left with a bunch of `U`s that we don't know what to do with, because the `BiFunction` only takes a `U` and `T` and gives a `U` back. We need an extra `BinaryOperator<U>` to help us *combine* the `U`s.

So the combiner is necessary if you want a different result type.

---

Also, `20` is not a valid identity value. A valid identity must satisfy

```
accumulator.apply(identity, u) == u
```

for all `u` for the combiner-less version, and

```
combiner.apply(u, accumulator.apply(identity, t)) == accumulator.apply(u, t)
```

for all `u` and `t` for the combiner version.